# If the convolution of the exponential function and a function tends to 0 when the time tends to infinity, can we get the following conclusion?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

If we know $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-\tau)}\phi(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau=0,\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{At}=0$, can we get:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\phi(t)= 0$$
?

Comment: Are you missing two integral signs? What does $e^{At}dt \to 0$ mean?

Comment: Why would this be true or false ? Have you tried with simple examples ?

Comment: @FiMePr,no, there is an article that directly gets this conclusion.

Comment: You edited the question, but there is still $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t = 0$, what do you mean with that?

Comment: @SampleTime, sorry, I have revised the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it seems to be incorrect.

If you let $\phi(\tau) = \cos(\tau^2)$, then $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow \infty} \phi(\tau) \neq 0$, but the rapid oscillation of $\phi$ makes the convolution go to $0$ anyway. I haven't proven this rigorously, but it shouldn't be too hard. Numerically, with $A = -1$
and
$$
F = \int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)} \cos(\tau^2) d \tau,
$$
we get the following values:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(1) &= \phantom{-}0.55 \\
F(10) &= -0.023 \\
F(100) &= -0.00155 \\
F(1000) &= -0.000175 \\
F(10000) &= \phantom{-}0.000046
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Edit: Previous comment is obsolet. Maple can solve this integral (its a bit complicated) but it can compute that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} F(t) = 0$.

Comment: Using the same idea, with $\phi(\tau) = \sin(e^{\tau})$ the proof becomes even easier because then $F(t) = 2 e^{-t} \big( \cos(\frac{1}{2})^2 - \cos(\frac{e^t}{2})^2 \big)$ and then also $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} F(t) = 0$ but $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sin(e^{t}) \neq 0$.