# Doubts about the stability of a system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

For the following dynamic system:
$$\dot{x} = Ax + f(t)$$
$f(t)$ is piecewise continuous and differentiable. If for any bounded initial value, we know $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}x(t) = 0$.We can get $A$ is Hurwitz, but we can’t seem to get $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f(t) = 0$, [in the last question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758778/if-the-convolution-of-the-exponential-function-and-a-function-tends-to-0-when-th), we can see that the limit of $f(t)$ may not exist. Therefore, I have a doubt, how to restrict the condition of $f(t)$ so that we can get the necessary and sufficient condition of $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }x(t) = 0$. In other words, what conditions does $f(t)$ meet to make the following conclusions true?
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }x(t) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow A\quad\mathrm{is}\quad \mathrm{Hurwitz} \quad \&\& \quad \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f(t) = 0$$

Comment: I am not sure if you even can get that $A$ is Hurwitz... How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @SampleTime, what you said seems to be right, should the conclusion be revised to $\dot{x} = Ax$ is asymptotically stable?

Comment: Well, that is the same because $\dot{x} = A x$ is asymptotically stable if and only if $A$ is Hurwitz.

Comment: @SampleTime, eh.. how do you think the modification makes the conclusion reasonable?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand which conclusion you mean... by using "$\dot{x} = A x$ is asymptotically stable" instead of "$A$ is Hurwitz" you didn't change anything because those two statements are equivalent.

Comment: @SampleTime, the conclusion I mean is if the trajectory of dynamical system $\dot{x} = Ax + f(t)$ satisfies $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} x(t) = 0$ for any bounded initial value, what characteristics should $A$(you first thought that "$A$ is Hurwitz" is incorrect) and $f(t)$ have?

Comment: A sufficient conditions would be that $A$ is Hurwitz and $f$ is bounded and decays to zero eventually. I don't  know however if these are also necessary conditions.

Comment: @TangHsiangyu : If $A^T+A<0  \ \ \& \ \ Ax+f(t)=0$ only at $x=0$  $\& \ \ f(t) \cdot x<0 \ \ \forall x , t $ this should do the trick , but it is rather conservative .

Comment: @abc1455 If $A x + f(t) = 0$ this implies that $f(t) = -A x$ so you end up with the trivial system $\dot{x} = 0$. I don't really see how that helps, because this system isn't even asymptotically stable.

Comment: @SampleTime : no $\dot{x} =0$ only at the origin i.e. the origin is the only equilibrium point .

Comment: @abc1455 Ok but to ensure that $A x \neq -f(t)$ for all $x \neq 0$ you need to know the trajectories? I don't see how to use that in practice. The condition that $f$ is bounded should be much easier to check I guess.

Comment: @SampleTime : I think this condition is not necessary to proof this consider lyapunov  $V=\frac{1}{2}x^Tx \implies \dot{V}=x^T\dot{x}=x^TAx+x^T f(t)  \leq 0$ since $x \cdot f(t) \leq 0$ and $\dot{V}$ is only zero at $x=0$ so the system is globally asymptotically stable to the origin , but these are conservative conditions as they say that the system $\dot{x}=f(t)$ is stable .

Comment: @abc1455 True. Getting necessary conditions (other than the Lyapunov ones) might be difficult or even impossible.

Comment: @SampleTime : I think yours is better , if $f(t)$ eventually vanishes , the system will converge to the origin , provided that the linear part is stable .

Comment: @SampleTime, In fact, ''$f$ is bounded and decays to zero eventually'' is a bit conservative. According to Khalil’s book, we can know that if $f(t)$ satisfies certain increasing conditions, we can get system is asymptotically stable.

Comment: @TangHsiangyu Ok, but "certain increasing conditions" is a bit vague. You should probably update your question with this information.